# How to close hamburger menu on keyboard accessibility focus out

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, accessibility, screen-readers

I am trying to implement keyboard accessibility in one of my website for blind people. I have a hamburger menu on my website. While navigating using the "Tab" key on the keyboard, the focus moves to this hamburger menu item. While clicking on "Enter", it will expand and while press the "Tab" key again, it is navigating through the open hamburger menu elements. Once the last item reached, it will focus on the content.

In that case, is it possible to close the hamburger menu once the user focus-out using the keyboard "Tab" keypress?

Example here https://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/hamburger-menu/. It is possible to close the side menu after focus out?

Comment: Please post your code here for review. I looked your url and I can see the nav menu that appears has an unordered list but none of the required roles, and the nav that opens is not in the nav element, it's in main, which I think is confusing but doesn't fail the SiteImprove chrome extension test I ran on it. See here for more: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/application-menus/. And add a skip link to go directly to the main content of the page and skip the menu: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G1

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

It's possible, but it isn't a good idea.
You'd better use a classic toggle button.

#### Longer answer

For a blind person, doing something on focus out essentially means that it happens without notice. It may be hard to understand and is at best a source of confusion.
The elements that are successively reached in tab navigation and their order aren't supposed to change without explicit conscious user action.

It's even more confusing  if the way in which the menu appears and disappears aren't symetric (in your case, explicit press enter vs. focus out).
Both should be symetric. This means that, whether:

- The same button toggle the menu on and off
- The menu appears on leaving the link just before the menu (focus in), and disappears when leaving the last item of the menu (focus out)

There are several important cons in implementing the second:

- Tab isn't the only way to navigate on a page for screen reader users. This concretely means that the menu may not be reachable for  no apparent reason, and there may not be any way to make it appear.
- Keyboard-only users having vision will probably be surprised of unexpected appearance/disappearance of the menu
- Technically it isn't as easy as it looks like: you must think about it in the two directions (tab and shift+tab)

The toggle button hasn't these problems. Correctly implemented, it's always reachable, explicitly triggered by the user and has predictable behavior.
Additionally, it's much simpler to implement.

To wrap it up, the classic toggle button is therefore by far the simplest and safest solution, both for you and for users of various kinds.

Comment: In case the toggle button opens modal-like menu, do you think it would be better to have the menu toggle button in the same tab/shift+tab loop as the menu items or should the focus loop from last menu item to first and user should just guess to press Esc to exit the loop? That would change where tab goes when focus is in the menu toggle button depending on if the button is pressed or not.

Comment: In fact the best would be to have both: react to escape and have the button inside the menu, so that you cover the whole range from newbie to power users.
However, if you have to choose one or the other, escape is very common, so I would say that both are acceptable.
Note that the focus should go back to the toggle button when pressing escape.